# Excel Userform Textbox Drag or Drag away

Tags: excel, drag-and-drop, userform, vba

If I enable the Drag and Drop behaviour for a textbox on an Excel userform, I can trigger an event simply by hovering the mouse over the texbox. If I then move the mouse away without dropping the item onto the texbox, I want the event to be cancelled. Is there any way I can do this?

Simple example: I hover the mouse over the textbox, a checkbox is ticked. I move the mouse away without dropping and the checkbox is un-ticked.

Answer (score 1):

By validating the `DragState` of the mouse I was able to do this:

```
If DragState = fmDragStateLeave Then
```